# menu not visible on tablet

Tags: android

After hours of browsing the internet, I am still having a problem showing a menu on my app.
I have a viewflipper with in it several scrollviews and they have several layouts as well.
The whole app works great, I can swipe from scrollview to scrollview without any problems.

Before I connected a Samsung Galaxy Tab to play with, I was running the app in the emulator. There if I pressed the menu button, the submenu was showing and I was able to run functions on menu item touch.

On the tablet, the menu is not showing anywhere.

Here is my menu file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/KPNsites"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_name"
        android:title="KPN Sites"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/VDFsites"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_name"
        android:title="Vodafone sites"/>

</menu>
```

In my activity I have this code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu my_menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, my_menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(my_menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.KPNsites:

            getKPNsiteInfo();
            return true;

        case R.id.VDFsites:

            getVodafoneSiteInfo();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

When I run the app on the tablet, I only have a small bar at the top with only te app-name in it. I suspect the menu should be visible on that bar?

What else should I do / have done (differently)??

rg,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well gave it up for now.
every try messes up what I already got.

To get by, I've put buttons on the layout.

May be with the next project I get it working.
(but then by starting with it before I have all my layouts finished)

Thanks for the help!

rg,
Eric

Answer (score 3):

If your tablet is running Android 3.0 or greater you should change targetSdkVersion to <= 10 in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) this will give your app uniform and modern look on any Android version.

Comment: While it involves a good chunk of work, this is, ultimately, the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

[Menu Example](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-action-bar-tab-menu-example)